# Verification of CMAC

Tags: security, communication

How to Verify CMAC in install for install command in javacard..

I used the process given below but this method not able to verify

1. Key = Session Key for CMAC,
   IV =  CMAC which is given in external authenticate command,
   Message = First 8 bytes of install for install command
2. Use same key,
   IV = Output of previous step,
   Message = Next 8 bytes of install for install command

this steps until all blocks of install for install command taken at DES-3Key
if last block of install for  install command not multiple of 8 than add ISO9797_M2 padding

The Result of last block is taken as CMAC.